# MySQL - ordering results based on order of subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to order my rows for a table based on the order of a subquery. At least, that is what I think I am trying to do!

The task I am looking at is to record some stats, and then (after some other changes), get the same stats again in a format where it is easy to compare. I'm writing a simple report that shows the before-and-after stats - so I want my rows to be grouped together.

So first step is to get the initial stats - it's stats about the DB size:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_stats;
CREATE TABLE db_stats ( id INT UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, table_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, data_length BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, index_length BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, table_rows BIGINT NOT NULL, avg_row_length SMALLINT NOT NULL, description VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE INDEX unique_key(table_name,description));
INSERT INTO db_stats (table_name,data_length,index_length,table_rows,avg_row_length,description)(SELECT table_name, data_length,index_length,table_rows,avg_row_length, "before" FROM information_schema.tables);
```

Step 2 - I truncate the biggest table in my database.

Step 3 - new stats:

```
INSERT INTO db_stats (table_name,data_length,index_length,table_rows,avg_row_length,description)(SELECT table_name, data_length,index_length,table_rows,avg_row_length, "after" FROM information_schema.tables);
```

Now, find the top 3 tables:

```
SELECT table_name, description, table_rows 
FROM db_stats 
WHERE table_name IN ( SELECT table_name 
                      FROM db_stats 
                      WHERE description = "before" 
                      ORDER BY data_length + index_length DESC) 
ORDER BY data_length + index_length DESC LIMIT 6
```

Let's say my tables are called table1, table2, table3 etc. (ordered by the total size). My results here are

```
table1, "before"
table2, "before"
table2, "after"
table3, "before"
table3, "after"
table4, "before" <--- I didn't want this one
```

I want table1, "after" to be 2nd on the list, because I want the table1 before count, then after, then table2, and so on. But I don't get it here because the size is now 0 since I truncated it. Any ideas?

I think part of my problem could be that I just don't know if there is a name for this technique; I've tried searching for stuff about ordering/sub-queries but couldn't really find anything that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT d.table_name, d.description, d.table_rows 
FROM db_stats d
JOIN db_stats x ON d.table_name = x.table_name
                AND x.description = "before"
ORDER BY x.data_length + x.index_length DESC,
         d.table_name,
         d.description DESC
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to use a limit for a subquery is to join with it, not use it in the where clause;

```
SELECT db_stats.table_name, db_stats.description, db_stats.table_rows 
FROM db_stats 
JOIN ( 
  SELECT table_name FROM db_stats WHERE description = 'before' 
  ORDER BY data_length + index_length DESC LIMIT 3
) q ON db_stats.table_name = q.table_name
ORDER BY data_length + index_length DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6976/1).

Comment: Thank you. Not enough reputation to up-vote but I will come back when I do.